# Transform a pandas series, new mean and stddev

Tags: python

If you have a series, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.series = [1.01, 2, 1.2, 3.1, 4.32, 1.23, 8.21, 4.2, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 5.2, 4.8, 4.2, 5.98, 6.1, 2.9, 4.12, 4.78, 5.56, 5.21]
```

What if want to force a transformation on this series, to have a mean of 10 and a std dev of 2.

How would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to append some records or modify in-place some values? For example to have a mean of 10, you can use `(sr + 10 - sr.mean())`. The mean is now 9.9999999999999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
sr = pd.Series([1.01, 2, 1.2, 3.1, 4.32, 1.23, 8.21, 4.2, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3,
                5.2, 4.8, 4.2, 5.98, 6.1, 2.9, 4.12, 4.78, 5.56, 5.21])
std = 2
mean = 10

out = mean + (sr - sr.mean()) * std / sr.std()
```

Output:

```
>>> out.mean()
10.0

>>> out.std()
2.0

>>> out
0      7.029798
1      8.062243
2      7.227944
3      9.209403
4     10.481708
5      7.259230
6     14.538484
7     10.356563
8      7.332231
9      8.375104
10     9.417978
11    11.399436
12    10.982287
13    10.356563
14    12.212877
15    12.338022
16     9.000828
17    10.273133
18    10.961430
19    11.774871
20    11.409865
dtype: float64
```

All explanation here: [Transform Data to Desired Mean and Standard Deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/46429)